# Scrolling to the bottom of a page that changes height

Tags: javascript

I want to scroll to the bottom of a webpage using JS and, looking online, most people say to use

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

However the page I want to scroll down changes its height as you reach the bottom (it continuously loads more and more of the page) so its height is not fixed. The eventual height also varies (thus I cannot just scroll to the final height of the page) so I need some way of scrolling until it determines it has reached the bottom (it cannot scroll any further).

Answer (score 1):

If you have infinite scroll, you actually need to incorporate that in your design. E.g. `scrollToBottom` should look like this:

```
function scrollToBottom(lastOffset) {
  const offset = document.body.scrollHeight;
  // check if no more scrolling required.
  if (lastOffset === offset)  {
    return;
  }
  // if it is, go to bottom.
  window.scrollTo(0, offset);
  // Now, trigger your `loadMore` logic, whatever it might be, then call scrollToBottom again.
  triggerLoadMore().then(() => scrollToBottom(offset));
  // or triggerLoadMore(() => scrollToBottom(offset));
}

// call this somewhere after your initial load.
```

Now, `triggerLoadMore`, erm, triggers your **loadMore** logic. I included two versions in the above code, one being promise-based, the commented one being callback-based. It should call back your function (scrollToBottom) when it has loaded more and put it on the screen. How you do that, depends on what you use, and is possibly another question.

Now, there's a third option here, that your trigger is something that you cannot call directly, because it's tied to `window.scroll` event or some such logic. In that case, you need to write this bit of logic at the end of such function flow - load more, render on screen, scroll. Which then triggers the cycle again.

Answer (score 0):

@Zlatko answer is the best performance. However, you can use this one in every context :

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', function(){
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to reach bottom of the page, wait for load and scroll to bottom again. You can't reach the end of the page where you cannot know the end.

```
function scroll_and_wait(){
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
    resolve(window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight));
    }, 500);})}

 async function scroller(n){while(n>0){await scroll_and_wait();n=n-1;}}

 scroller(5)
```

Calling `scroller` function will scroll to to bottom of the page as many times as you specify with 500ms pause for loading.